# Let $|G|=p^nm$ where $p$ is a prime and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.Suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $|G|=p^nm$ where $p$ is a prime and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.Suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ of order $p^n$. IF $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $p^k$, show that $K \subseteq H$.

**Attempt:** Given that $|G|=p^nm$ and $gcd(p,m)=1 => \gcd(p^n,m)=1$

$H \triangleleft G =>g^{-1}hg \subseteq H~~ \forall ~~g\in G, h\in H$

$G/H=\{gH ~~\forall~~g \in G \}$ and then $|G/H|=p^nm/p^n=m$

Now, $O(gH)~~|~~O(g)$ and $O(g)~~|~~p^nm$

$=> O(gH)~~|~~p^nm ..........(1)$

$O(gH)~~|~~m ....... (2) $

( By Lagrange's Theorem, $gH$ is an element in $G/H$ and $O(gH) ~~|~~|G/H|$ and $|G/H|=m$)

Since $\gcd(p^n,m)=1 => O(gH)= r $ s.t. $r$ divides $m$.
$=> g^r \in H$

If we show that $\exists h_1,h_2 \in H $ s.t. $k=h_1h_2$ then our result can be proved or if we prove that $K$ is a normal subgroup in $H$ and $|H : K|=1$, then also we can prove the result

How should I proceed ahead. Help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you come across the Sylow theorems?

Comment: No, not yet. I guess they appear later in Gallian. Not very far though

Comment: Ok then I give you a hint with which you can compare orders of groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the claim follows (and is proved along) the standard Sylow theorems presumably we are not allowed to use that.

Hints:

- Given that $H\unlhd G$ show that $KH=\{kh\mid k\in K, h\in H\}$ is a subgroup of $G$.
- Show by counting cosets of $H$ inside $KH$ that the order of $KH$ is $|KH|=|H|\cdot [K:H\cap K]$. This is a power of $p$.
- Apply Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Sir, I am not getting how it follows from your hints that $K\subseteq H$ please elaborate

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $HK/H \cong K/(H \cap K)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $g \in K, g \notin H$. Then $(gH)^m=H=(g^m)H \implies g^m∈H \implies (g^m)^{p^l}=e=(g^{p^l})^m$ for some $l$ But $g^{p^l} \in K$ As the order of K is $p^k$ the equality $(g^{p^l})^m=e$ is impossible. Proof is ended

Comment: Please try to format your answers so that they reach more people.